# How to customize the Uninstall alert Dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, uninstallation

I'm developing an android application .In that app , I wanna uninstall an application my app .

I've used the following snippets ,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
                  intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" +     ((ResolveInfo)list.get(position)).activityInfo.packageName));
                 c.startActivity(intent);
```

The uninstall alert is opened and uninstalling done fine .But I want to customize the uninstall alert dialog . How to do that ?

Comment: I think that dialog is part of Android. You might not be able to change it.

Comment: actually you dont need to do this. this job will done by android ..j

Answer (score -1):

Can be try from this code...............................

```
public void btFirst(View v) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("ALERT>>>>>");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("UNINSTALL")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.example.pp");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
                startActivity(intent);      

                //MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
          })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();


}
```

Comment: If I do this means again the default dialog box will be opened as you're using the same Intent snippets :-(. please suggest me if any other options if any